# Expression must have pointer-to-object type Error?

Tags: visual-c++

[Updated Code Pictutre][1]Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong with my array in this code? It is giving me the same error for all my variables of the array

I dont know how to show you the whole code without adding like 5 pictures, i tried to capture all the important information

Ok I have posted the code here below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
// output for a single input driving frequency 

double m, c1, c2, k1, k2, r, Y;
m = c1 = c2 = k1 = k2 = r = Y = 0;
//input values for the case
cout << "Mass: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "c1: ";
cin >> c1;
cout << "c2: ";
cin >> c2;
cout << "k1: ";
cin >> k1;
cout << "k2: ";
cin >> k2;
cout << "r: ";
cin >> r;
cout << "Y: ";
cin >> Y;
//solve for the equivlent values 
double ceq, keq, wn, dampratio, staticamp;
ceq = c1 + c2;
keq = k1 + k2;

wn = 0;
wn = sqrt(keq / m);
dampratio = ceq / (2 * sqrt(m*keq));

//Determine the Case
double cas = 0;
cout << "Which Case (1-5): ";
cin >> cas;

double Fo, alpha, w, t;

if (cas == 2) {
    Fo = Y*k2;
}
else {
    w = r*wn;
    t = 0;
    Fo = 0;
    Fo = Y*sqrt((k2*k2 + pow((c2*w), 2)));

    alpha = atan(-c2*w / k2);
}
//Static amplitude 
staticamp = 0;
staticamp = Fo / keq;

double Xp = (Fo / keq) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));
double phi = atan((ceq*w) / (keq - m*w*w));
double xp = Xp*sin(w*t - phi);

double H, Td, Ftwall, Ftbase;

//Displacement Transmissiblity
Td = 0;
Td = (Fo / (Y*keq)) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));

//Frequanecy Response
H = 0;
H = 1 / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));

//Force Transmissibilty to the bang
Ftbase = 0;
Ftbase = (Xp*sqrt(pow((k1 - keq*r*r), 2) + pow((c1*wn*r), r))) / (Y*k2);

//Force Transmissibilty to the wall 
Ftwall = 0;
Ftwall = (Xp*sqrt((k1*k1) + pow((c1*r*wn), 2))) / (Y*k2);

if (cas == 5) {
    cout << "\nCase: " << cas << endl << endl;
    cout << "Wn: " << wn << endl;
    cout << "Damping Ratio: " << dampratio << endl;
    cout << "Amplitude: " << staticamp << endl;
    cout << "Frequency Response: " << H << endl;
    cout << "Phase Angle: " << phi << endl;
    cout << "Displacement Transmissibilty: " << Td << endl;
    cout << "Force Tranmissibility to the base: " << Ftbase << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "\nCase: " << cas << endl << endl;
    cout << "Wn: " << wn << endl;
    cout << "Damping Ratio: " << dampratio << endl;
    cout << "Amplitude: " << staticamp << endl;
    cout << "Frequency Response: " << H << endl;
    cout << "Phase Angle: " << phi << endl;
    cout << "Displacement Transmissibilty: " << Td << endl;
    cout << "Force Tranmissibility to the base: " << Ftbase << endl;
    cout << "Force Transmissibilty to the wall: " << Ftwall << endl;
}

//*****************************Section 1.2 **********************************************


// 1.2 output for a range of driving frequencies 
//input values for the case
cout << "Mass: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "c1: ";
cin >> c1;
cout << "c2: ";
cin >> c2;
cout << "k1: ";
cin >> k1;
cout << "k2: ";
cin >> k2;
cout << "Y: ";
cin >> Y;

//solve for the equivlent values 
ceq = keq = 0;
ceq = c1 + c2;
keq = k1 + k2;

wn = 0;
wn = sqrt(keq / m);                  //natural frequency
dampratio = ceq / (2 * sqrt(m*keq)); // damping ratio 

                                     //Determine the Case
cas = 0;
cout << "Which Case (1-5): ";
cin >> cas;

double  staticamp[200], Xp[200], xp[200], Fo[200], phi[200], w[200];
double alpha[200], Td[200], H[200], Ftbase[200], Ftwall[200], r[200];

r[1] = .1;

for (int i = 0; i<200; i++) {

    if (cas == 2) {
        Fo = Y*k2;
    }
    else {
        w = r[i] * wn;
        t = 0;
        Fo = 0;
        Fo = Y*sqrt((k2*k2 + pow((c2*w), 2)));

        alpha[i] = atan(-c2*w / k2);
    }
    //Static amplitude 
    staticamp[i] = 0;
    staticamp[i] = Fo / keq;

    Xp[i] = (Fo / keq) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r[i] * r[i]), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r[i]), 2)));
    phi[i] = atan((ceq*w) / (keq - m*w*w));
    xp[i] = Xp*sin(w*t - phi);

    //Displacement Transmissiblity
    Td[i] = 0;
    Td[i] = (Fo / (Y*keq)) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r[i] * r[i]), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r[i]), 2)));

    //Frequanecy Response
    H[i] = 0;
    H[i] = 1 / (sqrt(pow((1 - r[i] * r[i]), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r[i]), 2)));

    //Force Transmissibilty to the bang
    Ftbase[i] = 0;
    Ftbase[i] = (Xp*sqrt(pow((k1 - keq*r[i] * r[i]), 2) + pow((c1*wn*r[i]), r[i]))) / (Y*k2);

    //Force Transmissibilty to the wall 
    Ftwall[i] = 0;
    Ftwall[i] = (Xp*sqrt((k1*k1) + pow((c1*r[i] * wn), 2))) / (Y*k2);

    //increment r
    r[i + 1] = r[i] + .1;
}

ofstream Data(" 1.2 Case 1 .txt");                      // File Creation to import in text file to graph  
for (int i = 0; i > 200; i++) {                         //NEED TO CHANGE FILE NAME FOR NEW DATA SET
    Data << r[i] << "," << H[i] << "," << phi[i] << "," << Td[i] << "," << Ftbase[i] << "," << Ftwall[i] << endl;
}

//************************* Section 2 ****************

cout << "\t\tSection 2" << endl << endl;
//input values for the case
cout << "Mass: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "c1: ";
cin >> c1;
cout << "c2: ";
cin >> c2;
cout << "k1: ";
cin >> k1;
cout << "k2: ";
cin >> k2;
cout << "r: ";
cin >> r;
cout << "Y: ";
cin >> Y;
//solve for the equivlent values 
ceq = c1 + c2;
keq = k1 + k2;

wn = 0;
wn = sqrt(keq / m);
dampratio = ceq / (2 * sqrt(m*keq));

//Determine the Case

cout << "Which Case (1-5): ";
cin >> cas;



if (cas == 2) {
    Fo = Y*k2;
}
else {
    w = r*wn;
    t = 0;
    Fo = 0;
    Fo = Y*sqrt((k2*k2 + pow((c2*w), 2)));

    alpha = atan(-c2*w / k2);
}
//Static amplitude 
staticamp = 0;
staticamp = Fo / keq;

Xp = (Fo / keq) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));
phi = atan((ceq*w) / (keq - m*w*w));
xp = Xp*sin(w*t - phi);

//Displacement Transmissiblity
Td = 0;
Td = (Fo / (Y*keq)) / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));

//Frequanecy Response
H = 0;
H = 1 / (sqrt(pow((1 - r*r), 2) + pow((2 * dampratio*r), 2)));

//Force Transmissibilty to the bang
Ftbase = 0;
Ftbase = (Xp*sqrt(pow((k1 - keq*r*r), 2) + pow((c1*wn*r), r))) / (Y*k2);

//Force Transmissibilty to the wall 
Ftwall = 0;
Ftwall = (Xp*sqrt((k1*k1) + pow((c1*r*wn), 2))) / (Y*k2);

if (cas == 5) {
    cout << "\nCase: " << cas << endl << endl;
    cout << "Wn: " << wn << endl;
    cout << "Damping Ratio: " << dampratio << endl;
    cout << "Amplitude: " << staticamp << endl;
    cout << "Frequency Response: " << H << endl;
    cout << "Phase Angle: " << phi << endl;
    cout << "Displacement Transmissibilty: " << Td << endl;
    cout << "Force Tranmissibility to the base: " << Ftbase << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "\nCase: " << cas << endl << endl;
    cout << "Wn: " << wn << endl;
    cout << "Damping Ratio: " << dampratio << endl;
    cout << "Amplitude: " << staticamp << endl;
    cout << "Frequency Response: " << H << endl;
    cout << "Phase Angle: " << phi << endl;
    cout << "Displacement Transmissibilty: " << Td << endl;
    cout << "Force Tranmissibility to the base: " << Ftbase << endl;
    cout << "Force Transmissibilty to the wall: " << Ftwall << endl;
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: your out for loop. the terminate condition is wrong. It should be for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++); 
Please post whole code to your question

Comment: also, may be the type of your array is not appropriate. Why r is an array of int then r[1] is assign 0.1?

Comment: Please post your code here, as text. That way people can copy & paste it to try it out. A https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would also be more helpful than lots of incomplete code. Please edit and clarify your question. Which of the many arrays are you having trouble with? What trouble exactly? Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Im not sure how to post the entire code because it is quite long

Comment: @Gummy you can try ideone.com or break your code into several part (declaration, call, etc.). This is absolutely better than your capture image.

Comment: Ok I think I got the code up now

Comment: Ok I figured it out, thanks guys!